# How can I set up a 12 hour timer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I want to trigger a mechanism once every *real-time* 12 hours. Is this possible, or well out of the realms of plausibility?

I'm using the Direwolf modpack.

Comment: Do you require the timer to be deterministic?  Does it have to be exactly 12 hours, or can it be "on average" every 12 hours?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Yes

The simple way is to use a [timer](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Timer) with a ridiculously long time set. However, since you can only increment the time 10 seconds at a time, this would require 4320 clicks. A bit much.

We can do better with a simple circuit that uses *maths* to extend the time between pulses.

The number of seconds we want to count is **43200**. This can be expressed as **2^6 x 3^3 x 5^2**, or **64 x 27 x 25**. These three [coprime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) numbers can be used as the times on three timers, with the results [and](http://integratedredstone.wikispaces.com/Redpower+Logic)ed together. They will then only all pulse in step once every 12 hours.

All you need to do then is sync the timers by powering them on from the same line to disable them, and then powering them all off at the same time.

Comment: Maths?!? *gasp*

Comment: Minecraft: it's edumactional!

Comment: Note that anything RedPower creates a hell lot of lag every pulse, so plan accordingly.