# Redstone clock leaks current

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I built a small clock like the example at the beginning of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZbDchvk_ac). However, the pulse redstone is triggered each time the cobblestone blocks move over it, instead of just when the glass block goes over it. This is causing a pulse on every cycle of the pistons, rather than on every cycle of the glass block.

What changes do I need to make to the design in order to make this clock work? Should I consider a different design?

Comment: This particular design was broken by the 1.5.2 update.

Comment: You might also want to look at [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/104474/1351), which also deals with long duration timers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Version 1.5](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history#Blocks_.26_Items) included a whole load of new redstone mechanics, and as such the underlying redstone system changed a fair bit - breaking some devices.

What you have posted is an example. There are [plenty of other clocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Clock_circuit) you can make that work in newer versions, try one of those.